# Resources for similarity between embryos

Tags: evolution, development, embryology, visualization

Is there a scientific paper/reputable image resource out there which I can use that the embryos of different organisms (vertebrata) are similar in their early developmental stages(without falling into the ontogeny recapitulates phylogeny trap) ?

All I am able to find are the haeckel drawings or somethings that suspiciously look like haeckel drawings and after that debacle, I do not want to be using that.